# FTDI serial converter problems in python

Tags: python, ftdi

I’m trying to write a small piece of code in python to use FTDI chip. I am using pyserial and can send byte string that’s correct but I receive no response and I believe my device is waiting for serial number authentication or something like that.. any hints would be helpfull as I’m fairly new to programming

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you indicate what device the FTDI chip is connected to, as well as what a logic analyzer or appropriate oscilloscope detects when you probe the RX and TX lines while trying to run your code?

Comment: I do not have a logic analyzer unfortunately I’m just monitoring data sent and received with serial port monitor it’s connected rs232 FTDI chip

Comment: Please indicate how the serial monitor is connected and what it detects.

Comment: I’m using hhd software to monitor port and can see data transmitted when other software is running and can see what data is transmitted with my program.. however when I send the data something is not correct as I get no response from the device

Comment: It is connected virtually using hhd software.. watches data transmission however I feel like my device doesn’t except the command since it is likely hasn’t been enabled to communicate

Comment: In that case, we will need the datasheet and other details on the device in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import serial
import time



ser = serial.Serial('COM3')

if ser.isOpen:
    print(ser.name + 'Communication Open')

ser.bytesize = 8
ser.stopbits = 1
ser.baud = 9600

String = [0xff, 0x10, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x73]
String1 = [0xf4, 0x10, 0x6f, 0x01, 0x74]
String3 = [0xf4, 0x10, 0x6f, 0x02, 0x75]
String4 = [0xf4, 0x10, 0x6f, 0x03, 0x76]
String5 = [0xf4, 0x10, 0x6f, 0x04, 0x77]
String6 = [0xf4, 0x10, 0x6f, 0x05, 0x78]
String7 = [0xf4, 0x10, 0x6f, 0x06, 0x79]
String8 = [0xf4, 0x10, 0x6f, 0x07, 0x7a]
String9 = [0xf4, 0x10, 0x6f, 0x08, 0x7b]
String10 = [0xf4, 0x10, 0x6f, 0x08, 0x7c]

ser.write(String)
ser.read(8)
print(ser.read(8))
ser.write(String1)
print(ser.read(8))
ser.write(String2)
print(ser.read(8))

ser.close()
```

this my code im trying to use as it isnt totally complete just a start to see if I can get a response from the device